# Copy list of files in nested subdirectories

Tags: bash, subdirectory, cp

I have a set of subdirectories, with files inside them:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── file_a.type
│   ├── file_b.type
│   ├── file_c.type
│   └── file_d.type
├── dir2
│   ├── file_e.type
│   ├── file_f.type
│   ├── file_g.type
│   └── file_h.type
└── README.md
```

I can guarantee the uniqueness of each file name.  The directory naming convention is `n[some unique random number]`.

I have a text file with a subset of these files

```
file_g.type
file_a.type
file_e.type
```

I would like to copy all of the files matching the names in that text file to a new directory.

I have tried using xargs to copy, however this does not work because of the subdirectories.

```
xargs -a files.txt cp -t new_dir each
```

I could recursively copy all the files in the sub-directories to a new directory and go from there.
However this is not possible due to disk size and bandwidth issues.

What is an efficient way to do this using standard bash utilities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the file names in a file named `files.txt`:

```
while read file
do
    cp dir[12]/"${file}" -t new_dir
done < files.txt
```

With `xargs` it can be done like this:

```
xargs -a files.txt -IFILE bash -c 'cp dir[12]/"FILE" -t new_dir'
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `[12]` in `dir[12]`?  Is it a specialisation of the `dir` command? The command fails on my system because it looks for a directory literally called `dir[12]`, rather than resolving to anything.

Comment: @PrunusPersica No, `dir[12]` is there to match either `dir1` or `dir2` that you showed in your question.  If those are not the real directory names, update the question and put the real directory names in it and I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: thanks, that was ambiguous of me.  I guess in this case it would be something like `n*/"FILE"`?

Comment: @PrunusPersica ure, if your directories all starts with `n` - but be aware of that so does your `new_dir` directory so if the run the script when there's already files in that directory you may get _two_ copies done which is a bit unncessary.